# How to grep "a" and "aa" after a number?

Tags: linux, grep

My .txt file is having lines like below:

```
1a
1aa
2a
2aa
```

I want to do a particular task for "a" side and another particular task for "aa" side. To be more precise and clear the task which I am doing for "a" side should not work for "aa" side and similarly the task which I am doing for "aa" side should not work for "a" side.

For exammple:

- For "aa" side, I want to go to one directory
- For "a" side, I want to go to more than one directory.

How can I do that in my script?

Comment: You should specify whether you want to apply the actions in the order in which the lines occur, or are happy to process first all `a`-lines and then all `aa`-lines.

Answer (score 9):

```
grep -xE '[0-9]+a'
```

Greps for lines that consist e`x`actly of one or more decimal digits followed by `a`.

```
grep -xE '[0-9]+aa'
```

For the variant with `aa`.

`-E` is for *extended regexps* needed for `+`. With basic regexps and without `-x`, you can do:

```
grep '^[0-9]\{1,\}a$'
```

`^` and `$` matching respectively at the beginning an end of the line, and `\{1,\}` being the BRE equivalent of ERE `+` (some `grep` implementations also support `\+` for that and you could always use `[0-9][0-9]*`).

Comment: I don't think you need to match multiple digits between the begin of line and the first a, just checking for a single digit before `a` is sufficient. The reason is that you want to _exclude_ matching the second a in aa. I.e. `[0-9]a$` and `[0-9]aa$` are sufficient.

Comment: @MSalters, but that would match on `foo1a`

Comment: Indeed, but the question doesn't actually say what should happen with that anyway. In my reading, `foo1a`_should_ match. The question only talks about the suffix.

Comment: @MSalters, true, which is why I stated explicitly what solutions in the answer do match on.

Comment: i am using cat hostList.txt | grep -xE '[0-9]+a' and i am not getting any output. Similarly for aa side

Comment: @DeepMukherjee, then your `hostList.txt` is not as shown in your question. Possibly, lines have trailing spaces or invisible characters like CR ones if it comes from Microsoft systems.

Comment: ok i am using abc20cb1aa,abc20cb1a,abc20cb2aa,abc20cba in hostList.txt file. please tell me how to grep for that entries for both "aa" and "a" side

Comment: @DeepMukherjee, that's a different  question from what you asked here. If you have a different question, please ask it separately, but I think you should have enough pointers in this Q&A for you to figure it out.

Comment: @DeepMukherjee: have you looked at `tr`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Try the expressions in MSalters first comment.

Answer (score 3):

As the regular expression `a` also matches "aa", you should handle "aa" first in your script.

Another option is to use perl compatible regexp's (PCREs), grep has a `-P` option for enabling those, which does come with the warning

> This is highly experimental and `grep -P` may warn of unimplemented features

(at least the version I have, I don't know if they removed the option or changed/removed the warning in newer versions), or you could use `perl`. Then a regexp like `/a(?!a)/` should be useable in the "a" case.

Comment: `/a(?!a)/` matches on the second `a` in `aa`

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/sh

while read word; do
    case "$word" in
        *aa)    printf 'Got double "a": %s\n' "$word"   ;;
        *a)     printf 'Got single "a": %s\n' "$word"   ;;
        *)      printf 'Got weirdness:  %s\n' "$word"   ;;
    esac
done <file.in
```

Running this with the example data in `file.in`:

```
Got single "a": 1a
Got double "a": 1aa
Got single "a": 2a
Got double "a": 2aa
```

You could extend this with a loop over your files around the existing `while` loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

for name in ./*.in; do
    while read word; do
        case "$word" in
            *aa)    printf 'Got double "a": %s\n' "$word"   ;;
            *a)     printf 'Got single "a": %s\n' "$word"   ;;
            *)      printf 'Got weirdness:  %s\n' "$word"   ;;
        esac
    done <"$name"
done
```

This is assuming that you input files matches the pattern `*.in` and are located in the current directory.

Comment: Note that if you want to  read just one (`$IFS` separated with backslash understood as an escaper and line-continuation)  _word_ from each line, that would be `read word rest_ignored`. To read a line `IFS= read -r line`. With just one argument, [that's more `read remaining_words`](/a/209184)

Answer (score 1):

You can match the suffix `aa` with `aa$`. Matching the suffix `a` is a bit harder since logically `aa` ends with `a` as well. That's why you need `[^a]a$` to match a single a. The `[^a]` is an inverted character class, it's every character but an a.

Comment: Not a problem, as it is preceded by digits.